# Twitter timeline scraping error using Twint

Tags: python

I have an issue whereby the `Since` command in `twint` does not appear to be working. I can only scrape Tweets from the past 10 days.

I tried to modify the source files for `twint` as per the suggestion here but no luck: https://issueexplorer.com/issue/twintproject/twint/1253

Does anybody have any suggestions of a fix? Or alternate packages?

```
import twint

c = twint.Config()
c.Search = "biden"
c.Lang = "en"
c.Since = "2021-01-01"
c.Limit = 5000
c.Pandas = True
c.Show_hashtags = False     
c.Hide_output = True  
# Run search
try:
    twint.run.Search(c)
except:
    import nest_asyncio
    nest_asyncio.apply()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using **snscrape for scraping any amount of tweets from an account or by keyword**.

You can find more info in this [medium article](https://medium.com/dataseries/how-to-scrape-millions-of-tweets-using-snscrape-195ee3594721) on how to do it by keyword. Here is my code for scraping all tweets from a given account:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import re
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
import time
import sqlite3 as sq
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter


maxTweets = 5086

# Creating list to append tweet data to
tweets_list = []
source="Twitter"

# Using TwitterSearchScraper to scrape data
for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('from:peopleagainstVE').get_items()):
    if i>maxTweets:
        break
    print(i)
    tweets_list.append([tweet.id,tweet.url,tweet.user.username,tweet.content,tweet.date,source,tweet.retweetCount,tweet.likeCount,tweet.replyCount])

tweets_df = pd.DataFrame(tweets_list,columns=['Tweet_ID', 'URL', "Account_Name", 'Text', 'Datetime','Source','Number_Retweets', 'Number_Likes', 'Number_Comments'])


print(tweets_df)


data = tweets_df
sql_data = 'tweets2_PAVE.sqlite' #- Creates DB names SQLite
conn = sq.connect(sql_data)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tweets2_PAVE''')
data.to_sql('tweets2_PAVE', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False) # - writes the pd.df to SQLIte DB
pd.read_sql('select * from tweets2_PAVE', conn)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a limit to the number of Tweets which can be scraped?

Comment: As far as I know, there isn’t a limit.